# How to mock an EditText in android using Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-edittext, mockito

I am trying to write a `Unit Test` for a validator of my `android` Application. The validator accepts as parameter `EditText`, therefore I need to mock it. However the mocking does not work, forcing the `Test` to crash on calling the `when()` method with the exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

My code is:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyUnitTest
{

@Mock
Context mMockContext;

@Test
public void validateIsCorrect() {
     final EditText input = Mockito.mock(EditText.class);
     when(input.getText()).thenReturn(Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("123"));

...
}

}
```

The dependencies in `build.gradle` file are:

```
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

The method `getText()` of the `EditText` is not `private` or `final`. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to mock an `EditText` this way? How?

Answer (score 2):

When you're running a unit test, you're using a standard JVM context, not Android's context and that's why it's crashing: The `Editable.Factory` class and it's methods (like `getInstance()`) are not in the classpath. And they have not been mocked either.
What I'd do is to create a class that `implements Editable` with a `private` member to hold a string reference and use it to mock the `getText()` method.
Something like this:

```
class MockEditable implements Editable {

    private String str;
    public MockEditable(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    @Override @NonNull
    public String toString() {
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    public int length() {
        return str.length();
    }

    @Override
    public char charAt(int i) {
        return str.charAt(i);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence subSequence(int i, int i1) {
        return str.subSequence(i, i1);
    }

    @Override
    public Editable replace(int i, int i1, CharSequence charSequence, int i2, int i3) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Editable replace(int i, int i1, CharSequence charSequence) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Editable insert(int i, CharSequence charSequence, int i1, int i2) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Editable insert(int i, CharSequence charSequence) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Editable delete(int i, int i1) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Editable append(CharSequence charSequence) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Editable append(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Editable append(char c) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
    }

    @Override
    public void clearSpans() {
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilters(InputFilter[] inputFilters) {
    }

    @Override
    public InputFilter[] getFilters() {
        return new InputFilter[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void getChars(int i, int i1, char[] chars, int i2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setSpan(Object o, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void removeSpan(Object o) {
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] getSpans(int i, int i1, Class<T> aClass) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSpanStart(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSpanEnd(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSpanFlags(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int nextSpanTransition(int i, int i1, Class aClass) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You can then make use of this class

```
Mockito.when(input.getText()).thenReturn(new MockEditable("123"));
```

Comment: And how `EditText` class itself will be in classpath?

Comment: When running unit tests you get an android.jar file in the classpath with the very least you'd need to run your tests. This means, the `EditText` class will be there so that you can reference it, but it's methods implementation are empty, throwing runtime exceptions when you use them, therefore you need to mock them first to use them.

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you need to create your own Editable, couldn't you just mock that as well?

Comment: That would definitely work for this scenario too. But if you had to mock for 10 different strings, or mock more than one method (`MockEditable` just "mocks" `toString()`), I'd prefer (personal opinion) to use 10 instances of that `MockEditable` class, than to mock 10 times `Editable`. Just for re-usability of code

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this from a bit further away; I am asking myself: why does your validator need to know anything about Android specific classes?

What I mean is: I *assume* that your validator (in the end) has to check the properties of maybe a **String**, or something alike?

I would thus suggest to focus on separating concerns here:

1. Create a component that fetches a **String** from your EditText
2. Create a validator that works with such strings

Then you don't need any specific mocking for your validator in the first place!

Comment: I use the pattern MVP. An Activity or a Fragment registers its views on a "ViewManager", which performs the validations as well. I know I could extract the values from EditText and test a method that accepts only Strings. I would like nevertheless to execute tests which are not isolated from Android components.

Answer (score 2):

```
final EditText editText = Mockito.mock(EditText.class);
final ArgumentCaptor<Editable> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Editable.class);
Mockito.doNothing().when(editText).setText(captor.capture());
Mockito.when(editText.getText()).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        return captor.getValue();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this guys, it works for me:
Please don't forget to add the **MockitoAnnotations.init(this);** and also use

```
@Mock private EditTextView passwordField;

 @Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    when(rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_logout)).thenReturn(buttonLogout);
    when(rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_unlock)).thenReturn(buttonUnlock);
    when(rootView.findViewById(R.id.ScreenLock_PasswordTextField)).thenReturn(passwordField);

    when(passwordField.getText()).thenReturn(Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("asd"));
    when(application.getPassword()).thenReturn("asd");

    sut = new ScreenLockPresenterImpl(application, rootView, screenLockListener,
            logoutButtonClickListener);
}


@Test
public void testOnClickWhenOk() {
    sut.onClick(null);

    verify(passwordField).getText();
    verify(screenLockListener).unLock();
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for:
**when(passwordField.getText()).thenReturn(Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("asd"));**